# Parsing a simple text grammar with Superpower

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, superpower

I'm trying to create a parser with [Superpower](https://github.com/datalust/superpower). I have already taken a look to the samples I've found in the repo, but they are a bit difficult to understand, at least for a beginner like me :) So I came with this little challenge.

I have invented a very basic grammar just to learn. I have thought of an elevator that follows a list of instructions to go up, down and wait.

Example:

```
(UP 100),
(DOWN 200),
(DOWN 100),
(DOWN @1),
(UP @3),
(WAIT),
(UP 300)
```

As you see, it consists of a list of comma-separated verbs to move, for example, an elevator.

- The verbs are **UP**, **DOWN** or **WAIT**.
- Every verb is enclosed by parentheses: **( )**
- **UP** and **DOWN** require either an **absolute number** or a **relative number**, that indicates the floor to which the elevator should move. Relative floor numbers come with a @ before the number.
- **WAIT** doesn't accept any number, because it stops the elevator for a while.

I really would like to learn how to create a token based parser for this grammar as a start in order to understand how to use SuperPower.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/datalust/superpower/tree/dev/sample/DateTimeTextParser)? there is not much documentation beyond a [readme](https://github.com/datalust/superpower/blob/dev/README.md), but they do have some samples, and tests which show how grammars are built.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thanks for making StackOverflow a greater place.

Comment: @dlatikay Thanks, I know those samples, but still I cannot handle it. That's why I created this silly sample: just for the sake of learning. If you are capable of creating the parser I asked for with the existing docs, please, share.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Since it's a new tag for a relatively unknown library, it's not targeted to 99.9% of the users in StackOverflow as today, so it's meant to be answered by a reduced group of users (experts in the matter) who, by answering this question in SO will help future users solve a common scenario. Also, I consider that anyone that is using the library has more than enough context to answer. BTW, the creators of the lib point to this tag (https://github.com/datalust/superpower#getting-help).

Comment: @PatrickArtner You can be sure that I have already pinged the people in their Gitter room, to get the attention of the people using the library. StackOverflow is currently a hub for many communities, even for those who are so new that almost nobody know about them. Let them do. If you don't know about a topic, just skip the question, like most of us do.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Step 1** of writing any [Superpower](https://github.com/datalust/superpower) parser is to figure out what the token kinds are. You have something like:

```
// ECL - Elevator Control Language ;-)
enum EclToken {
    LParen,
    RParen,
    UpKeyword,
    DownKeyword,
    WaitKeyword,
    AtSymbol,
    Number,
    Comma
}
```

**Step 2,** write a `Tokenizer<EclToken>`. This is left as a direct programming task by Superpower v1 - there aren't many helpers to lean on, you just need to write the code as in [the examples](https://github.com/datalust/superpower/blob/dev/sample/IntCalc/ArithmeticExpressionTokenizer.cs).

The tokenizer takes the input string, strips out the whitespace, and figures out what the sequence of tokens is.

For your example input, the first line will be:

```
// (UP 100),
LParen, UpKeyword, Number, RParen, Comma
```

For tokens like `Number` that contain content, the span associated with the `Result<EclToken>` will point to the portion of the input string corresponding to the token. In this line, the number will be a `TextSpan` covering `100`.

**Step 3** is to figure out what you want to parse the input *into*. For programming languages with nested expressions, this is usually an AST. In the case of the ECL sample, it's pretty simple so you might cut it down to:

```
struct ElevatorCommand {        
    public int Distance; // + or -
    public bool IsRelative;
}
```

**Step 4**, the parser. This is usually embedded in a static class. The job of the parser is to build up more complex results (an `ElevatorCommand[]`, here), from simpler results (number, movement).

This is where Superpower does the heavy lifting, particularly with respect to expectations and errors.

```
static class EclParser 
{
    static TokenListParser<EclToken, int> Number =
        Token.EqualTo(EclToken.Number).Apply(Numerics.IntegerInt32);
}
```

The first thing we do is define the parser for numbers; this one applies a built-in `TextParser<int>` to the content of an `EclToken.Number` span.

You can see more parsing machinery in [this example](https://github.com/datalust/superpower/blob/dev/sample/IntCalc/ArithmeticExpressionParser.cs).

A few more clues to help you find the way (not syntax checked, let alone compiled/tested):

```
    static TokenListParser<EclToken, ElevatorCommand> Up =
        from _ in Token.EqualTo(EclToken.UpKeyword)
        from distance in Number
        select new ElevatorCommand {
            Distance = distance,
            IsRelative = false
        };

    static TokenListParser<EclToken, ElevatorCommand> Command =
        from lp in Token.EqualTo(EclToken.LParen)
        from command in Up // .Or(Down).Or(Wait)
        from rp in Token.EqualTo(EclToken.RParen)
        select command;

    static TokenListParser<EclToken, ElevatorCommand[]> Commands =
        Command.ManyDelimitedBy(Token.EqualTo(EclToken.Comma));
}
```

`Commands` is the completed parser that you can apply to the input.

It's best to build up the parser incrementally, testing each smaller parser on chunks of input they're expected to parse.

Comment: OK, I think I understand. Right now, I'm trying to create the parser :) For now, I have a doubt. You modelled the ElevatorCommand only with the distance and whether it's a relative command or not. But how would a WAIT command be represented?

Comment: Just a heads-up from nitpickers' corner, the `p` in `Superpower` is lowercase :-)

Comment: Cool! Sorry, I believe it's my PascalCaseMania :-P

Answer (score 3):

OK, I have finally managed to get it. It wasn't so difficult with 
@Nicholas Blumhardt's guidance :)

I have created [a project in GitHub](https://github.com/SuperJMN/ElevatorControlLanguage) to illustrate the scenario. Since the classes are big for a post, I'm linking to the files:

- This is the [tokenizer](https://github.com/SuperJMN/ElevatorControlLanguage/blob/master/Ecl/EclTokenizer.cs)
- This is the [class with the parsers](https://github.com/SuperJMN/ElevatorControlLanguage/blob/master/Ecl/EclParser.cs).